# Un lieu peut-il aussi bien être à « un pas » qu'à « deux pas » d'un autre quand il est « juste à côté » etc. ?

Tags: adverbes, locutions, nombres, indications-de-lieu, formulation

Sur Wiktionnaire je vois associé au nom *pas* pour la *(faible) distance* des « [dérivés](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas#D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9s) » comme la locution adverbiale « [à deux pas de](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_deux_pas) » et la locution « être à un pas de » ; on a aussi l'expression « [il n'y a qu'un pas (de ceci à cela)](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pas/58420?q=pas#58070) ». En résumé on a l'emploi figé pour *juste à côté*, puis l'emploi surtout au figuré pour la « proximité » des idées mais reste qu'on a toujours aussi l'emploi concret « [à X pas](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas) », un élément constitutif de la locution adverbiale.

- Couramment peut-on aussi employer *(à) **un** pas (de)* pour la
  courte distance dans une locution adverbiale signifiant *juste à
  côté* (concrètement, se référant à des lieux, *être à un/deux pas
  (de, d'ici)*...) ; le fait qu'on dise qu'il « il n'y a qu'un pas (de
  ceci à cela) » pour signifier entre autres « il n'y a qu'une courte
  distance », implique-t-il qu'on dise aussi que *ceci* « est à un pas
  » de *cela* concrètement (*juste à côté*) : peut-on expliquer ?
- Incidemment, hormis un contexte, à partir de combien de *pas*
  pense-t-on que l'emploi sort du champ de la locution adverbiale figée
  pour devenir une référence concrète à la distance impliquant l'unité
  de mesure (approximative) ?

Comment: J'avoue ne pas avoir très bien compris le sens de votre première question : Demandez-vous si l'emploi de *A est à un pas de B* (en conservant le sens de la locution) est courant ou sémantiquement  légitime ?

Comment: @aCOSwt ...le sens de la locution étant « juste à côté », oui, est-ce courant ? Ensuite la deuxième partie du premier point c'est [Larousse](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pas/58420?q=pas#58070), ils disent que « il n'y a qu'un pas (de ceci à cela) » peut signifier « il n'y a qu'une courte distance ». Parfois on a un tour ou une syntaxe différente qui restreint l'emploi et donc je demande si « il n'y a qu'un pas (de ceci à cela) » peut être reformulé en "ceci « est à un pas » de cela" comme on l'a avec _deux_...

Comment: @aCOSwt D'autre part il y a un prologue loufoque à la question, c'est une réflexion au sujet de la question « a step down ». Dans une réponse on dit que DeepL traduit « London is not a step down from Paris » en employant _à deux pas de_ alors qu'en fait le robot dit « à un pas de » et à mon avis c'est une erreur dans les deux cas mais c'est à ce moment-là que je me suis mis à réfléchir à la nuance que j'explore dans ma question...

Answer (score 2):

Je ne répondrai qu'à la question incidente car elle est marrante et surtout... à justifier.

Dans les locutions adverbiales imagées de l'expérience, mieux vaut être cohérent avec les autres si on veut être compris.

**5! Au grand max!**

On veut dire *pas beaucoup* ? *On les compte sur les doigts d'une (seule) main.*

Pas beaucoup c'est par conséquent inférieur ou égal à 5!

**Mais surtout pas 4!**

*On monte les marches quatre à quatre*, ça c'est vraiment beaucoup à la fois pour des enjambées non ?
Et puis quand *on se met en quatre*, c'est aussi pour dire une démultiplication surérogatoire de soi-même.
Je passe *couper les cheveux en quatre* ou *ne pas y aller par quatre chemins* qui, eux aussi évoquent un (trop) grand nombre.

Pas 4 donc, 4 c'est beaucoup (trop).

**Pas Trois non plus car c'est le bien ça trois. Le juste milieu. le ni trop, ni pas assez.**

*C'est à la troisième fois que l'on voit les maîtres*
*La meilleure chanson ne se dit que trois fois*
*Tierce fois c'est droit*
*Toutes les bonnes choses vont par trois*...

Nous resteront alors allez... 1 ou 2 pour dire pas beaucoup... ou 5!

Comment: Je suis relativement d'accord avec les conclusions (sauf le 5, si 4 est beaucoup, 5 l'est d'autant plus) invitant à se limiter à 1 ou 2, mais simplement parce que ce sont les plus idiomatiques, tout comme on ne voit pas 23 ou 52 chandelles quand on est sonné, mais 36, même si l'idée resterait la même peu importe le nombre.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui! Ton objection (5 > 4) est aussi juste mathématiquement qu'appropriée dans l'image. De fait 5 n'évoque pas tant une idée de beaucoup ou de peu mais plus précisément le max d'une quantité comptable facilement... Mais bon... je voulais juste commencer en fixant un max! :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. : Pas vraiment d'accord avec ton nombre de chandelles. La locution connue faisant référence à 36, si je dis <36 alors je signifierai *"pas complètement sonné"* et si je dis >36 alors je signifierai *plus que complètement sonné*. On observe la même chose avec les *dessous* (du théatre) devenus 36.